# Changing image based on location data output

Tags: geoip, maxmind

I am trying to show/echo users location on a webpage using maxmind geoip2 paid plan, I also want to show different images based on the state/city names output.

For example, if my webpage shows the user is from New York, I would like to show a simple picture of New York, if the script detects the user is from Washington, the image should load for Washington.

This is the snippet I have tried but doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 if 
$('span#region=("New York")') {
  // Display your image for New York
  document.write("<img src='./images/NY.jpg'>");
}
  else {
    document.write("<img src='./images/different.jpg'>");
  }


</script>
```

This is the code in the header.

```
  <script src="https://js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
      var onSuccess = function(geoipResponse) {
          var cityElement = document.getElementById('city');
          if (cityElement) {
              cityElement.textContent = geoipResponse.city.names.en || 'Unknown city';
          }

          var countryElement = document.getElementById('country');
          if (countryElement) {
              countryElement.textContent = geoipResponse.country.names.en || 'Unknown country';
          }

          var regionElement = document.getElementById('region');
          if (regionElement) {
              regionElement.textContent = geoipResponse.most_specific_subdivision.names.en || 'Unknown region';
          }


      };

      var onError = function(error) {
          window.console.log("something went wrong: " + error.error)
      };

      var onLoad = function() {
          geoip2.city(onSuccess, onError);
      };

      // Run the lookup when the document is loaded and parsed. You could
      // also use something like $(document).ready(onLoad) if you use jQuery.
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onLoad);
      </script>
```

And this simple span shows the state name in body text of the Html when the page loads.

```
<span id="region"></span>
```

now the only issue is the image doesn't change based on users location, what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is missing some code, but it looks like you are running some code immediately and some code in a callback, a better way to do it is to have all the code in the callback:

```
            // whitelist of valid image names
            var validImages = ["NJ", "NY"];
            // get the main image you want to replace
            var mainImage = document.getElementById('mainImage');
            if (mainImage) {
                // ensure there is a subdivision detected, or load the default
                if(geoipResponse.subdivisions[0].iso_code && validImages.includes( && geoipResponse.subdivisions[0].iso_code)){
                    mainImage.src = "./images/" + geoipResponse.subdivisions[0].iso_code + ".jpg";
                } else {
                    mainImage.src = "./images/different.jpg";
                }
            }
```

Then just have the image you want to replace be:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs%3D" id="mainImage" />
```

Notes:

1. If you are using a responsive image, make sure your transparent gif is the same ratio height of to width as your final image to avoid page reflows.
2. You will have to load the `different.jpg` in the `onError` callback as well.

Comment: Hey Aaron, this worked for me, thanks for taking the time to solve this.